# AppDomain code to load DLL works in VB but not in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Some time ago, I wrote a program in VB (called QueryViewer) that as part of it, loads dlls into a new app domain and executes them successfully.  I have since moved over to C# and converted this program from VB into C# but I've been never been able to get what I think is the correctly converted C# routine to work.  It always fails on the appdomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap call even though this code (in VB though) works fine.

Here is the original VB code that works:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Policy
Imports System.Security.Permissions

Public Class ClassLocalLoader
    Inherits MarshalByRefObject

    Private _appDomain As AppDomain
    Private _clsRemoteLoader As classRemoteLoader

    Public Sub New()

        Dim strAsmName As String
        Dim adSetup As AppDomainSetup

        Try

            strAsmName = [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly.GetName.Name

            adSetup = New AppDomainSetup()
            adSetup.ApplicationName = "Plugin"
            adSetup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

            Dim permSet As PermissionSet = New PermissionSet(PermissionState.None)
            permSet.AddPermission(New SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.AllFlags))

            Dim ev As Evidence = New Evidence()
            ev.AddHostEvidence(New Zone(SecurityZone.MyComputer))

            permSet = SecurityManager.GetStandardSandbox(ev)

            _appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Plugin", Nothing, adSetup, permSet, New StrongName() {})

            _clsRemoteLoader = CType(_appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(strAsmName, strAsmName & ".ClassRemoteLoader"), classRemoteLoader)

        Catch logerrorex As Exception When TCA.Display.ShowLine(logerrorex)

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadAssembly(ByVal strFilename As String)

        _clsRemoteLoader.LoadAssembly(strFilename)

    End Sub

    Public Function CreateInstance(ByVal bindingFlags As BindingFlags, ByVal constructorParams As Object()) As MarshalByRefObject

        Return _clsRemoteLoader.CreateInstance(bindingFlags, constructorParams)

    End Function

    Public Sub Unload()

        If _appDomain IsNot Nothing Then

            AppDomain.Unload(_appDomain)
            _appDomain = Nothing

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

And now, here is the converted C# code that doesn't:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.Policy;
using KellermanSoftware.NetLoggingLibrary;

public class ClassLocalLoader : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private AppDomain _appDomain;
    private ClassRemoteLoader _classRemoteLoader;

    public ClassLocalLoader()
    {
        try
        {
            String asmName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

            var adSetup = new AppDomainSetup
            {
                ApplicationName = "Plugin",
                ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
            };

            PermissionSet permSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
            permSet.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.AllFlags));

            Evidence ev = new Evidence();
            ev.AddHostEvidence(new Zone(SecurityZone.MyComputer));

            permSet = SecurityManager.GetStandardSandbox(ev);
            if (permSet != null)
            {
                _appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Plugin", null, adSetup, permSet);
                _classRemoteLoader = (ClassRemoteLoader)_appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(asmName, asmName + ".ClassRemoteLoader");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.LogExceptionEx(ex, "Exception raised while trying to load plugin.");
        }
    }

    public void LoadAssembly(string filename)
    {
        Assembly.LoadFrom(filename);
    }

    public MarshalByRefObject CreateInstance(BindingFlags bindingFlags, Object[] constructorParams)
    {
        return _classRemoteLoader.CreateInstance(bindingFlags, constructorParams);
    }

    public void Unload()
    {
        if (_appDomain != null)
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(_appDomain);
            _appDomain = null;

        }
    }
}
```

The C# code fails with the following error:

Could not load type 'QueryViewer.ClassRemoteLoader' from assembly 'QueryViewer, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

The call that is made that causes the failure is just the following:

```
    classLocalLoader = new ClassLocalLoader();
```

Anyone see anything wrong with my converted C# routine that would cause this to fail?

Thanks,
Don B.

Comment: Have you stepped through both sets of code to compare the values passed into the `_appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` to see if anything is off?

Comment: There are some obvious differences: 1. the way you assign to _appDomain is different than your original VB.  2. in the original VB code you call _clsRemoteLoader.LoadAssembly, but in your C# code you call Assembly.LoadFrom.  You should try to keep as much constant as possible when converting so you can isolate problems easier.

Comment: Sadly, the error occurs on createinstanceandunwrap call and you can't check the value of _appDomain due to a VS2015 error about not being able to view transient data or something like that. So, no, I'm not able to see what is different.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will fix and retry.  Note however that I never get to the loadfrom function as it fails within the class instantiation.